# Android Room Inner Join Selects multiple rows

Tags: android, mysql, sql, kotlin, android-room

I am using the following query in Android Room to obtain values from two tables related by the foreign key. `Item` is the foreign key of `Transaction` related by column `upc`. `unique_id` is a unique transaction number.

```
 @Query("SELECT * FROM Transaction t INNER JOIN Item i ON i.upc=t.item_upc WHERE t.unique_id=:uniqueId")
    LiveData<List<TransactionItem>> getTransactionItemsByUID(@NonNull final String uniqueId);
```

When I run this command with unique transaction id, the query selects all the rows in `Transactions` where the `upc` are the same regardless of the `WHERE` clause. Basically, transactions with different `unique_id` are selected. However, I am only interested in  row with exact match to the `unique_id`.

The `TransactionItem` class is defined as follows.

```
// TransactionItem Model

@Embedded
public ItemModel itemModel;

@Relation(parentColumn = "upc", entityColumn = "item_upc", entity = Transaction.class)
public List<Transaction> transactions;
```

I have spent two days googling and reading but still couldn't find the right solution. What am I overlooking here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You telling to get Transaction and Item by INNER JOIN and then to get TransactionItem list for Item got by Transaction by @Relation JOIN, no WHERE.

You want get Transaction and Item not Transaction Item list, so TransactionItem not correct way. You want @Embedded Transaction and @Relation with ItemModel like

```
@Embedded
public Transaction transaction;
@Relation(parentColumn = "item_upc", entityColumn = "upc", entity = ItemModel.class)
public ItemModel itemModel;
```

Guessing 1 Item needed only. Can do `public List<Item> itemModels` if wanted.

You use

```
@Transaction
@Query("SELECT * FROM Transaction WHERE unique_id=:uniqueId")
LiveData<List<TransactionItem>> getTransactionItemsByUID(@NonNull final String uniqueId);
```